# plm "empty model" error - how to correct panel data?

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

After days of searching for an answer to my problem, reading guide documents, questions and answers here and elsewhere, I decided to ask this community.
I am new to R (and R Studio), coming from working with Stata only, and I am having trouble with performing a regression using panel data and the plm function.

What I want to estimate is how much better an investment model ("**P_Model**") is at identifying firms that tend to increase share price over time, controlling for **Country** and industry **Sector**.
I created an Excel file structured as it should be for panel data (as far as I know), and can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z76gg3n9tnpaxwv/DadosBase%20-%20R%20Studiov5.csv?dl=0) (all data there is public so there is no privacy or data issues). There are only 7 variables:

"**Company**" -> the firms.

"**t**"       -> time period.

"**Country**"

"**Sector**"  -> industry.

"**Subsector**"-> industry subsector (this was out of curiosity, not used for the main regression).

"**P_Model**" -> binary variable that is 0 for all firms that were chosen at random and not using the model, and 1 for those that were.

"**ValoPP**"  -> this is the firm's stock price return on investment from day 1, in percentage points.

After loading the data to R, I tried several different suggestions of how to perform the panel regression, but they all give this error:
[image: R input and error]

I believe the problem has to be with the panel structure I am using, but I can't find out what this is, as every firm has one of each of the other variables and only one time variable.

EDIT:

I created a simple test to check whether the issue was with coding or statistical concepts, and it seems to be definitively the latter. I used the following data and tried to run the same regression as above, getting the same error:

[image: Simple Test]

I tried to find out the impact of being a Male on the GPA of 3 students in 3 years. What concept am I getting wrong?

I have edited this post to adjust for this shift of focus.

Comment: There might be some statistical content in that question, but it could be a programming questions well. The variable `P_Model` does not seem to vary per Company (at a quick glance, did not check thoroughly), it could be perfectly collinear with Country and/or Sector, thus dropping out of the model and, hence, empty model. Also, you do not disclouse what kind of model you want to estimate.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. The P_Model varies per company, though it is a dummy variable that is only "1" for 37 out of the 300+ companies, but I understand that it is not perfectly collinear with either Country or Sector because the process I used for randomization was: for each firm with P_Model = 1, I added 10 firms from the same country and sector. So there is at least 2 countries and 2 sectors for each P_Model = 1. Regarding the kind of model, I understand that due to the controls I chose, a random effects model would be best. Please let me know if I misunderstood your comments.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand exactly why, but I solved the issue with the panel data.
Apparently, the problem was that I was adding "Company" in the panel index. In other words:

I was using this:

*pdata <- pdata.frame(mydata, **index = c("Company","t")**)*

And I should have been using this:

*pdata <- pdata.frame(mydata, **index = "t"**)*

With that, the problem was fixed and the regression ran correctly.

Comment: You want to check if the way you specified the index variables is what you want, e.g., look at `index(pdata)` to see what the individual and time dimension looks like.

Answer (score 0):

For the ones searching for this answer, the whole thing is that for using plm you have to declare your series as a panel data series. To check whether you have set this or not, use `class(df)`; if is not `pdata.frame` you should